# dart BrowserClient - how to read response headers?

Tags: http, dart

I don't manage to read response headers using browser_client.dart :

```
import 'package:http/browser_client.dart';


var response =
await client.post(url, headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json'
}, body: body);
print('Response headers: ${response.headers}');
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This works for me. Perhaps the server doesn't send the headers or they are suppressed by the browser because of CORS issues? (`Access-control-allow-headers`, `Access-control-expose-headers`)?

Comment: Thanks, `Access-control-expose-headers` was missing... It works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server needs to allow the browser to expose the headers by listing the headers in the `Access-control-expose-headers` response header, otherwise you can see them in the browser devtools but when you try to read them in code, the browser will suppress them.

See also

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
- [Why is Access-Control-Expose-Headers needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673089/why-is-access-control-expose-headers-needed)