# Reading Custom HTTP response headers in Angular 2

Tags: angular

In my angular 2 application , I am making a HTTP POST request to a service(HTTPS) , the HTTP response returned by service 
has a custom RESPONSE header "X-COUNT", but in below code the console.log does not print info about custom header "X-COUNT" , but it does print 
info about other headers.

```
this._http.post(restUri, postdata, options)
            .map(itemsResult =>
            { 
                console.log(JSON.stringify(itemsResult.headers));
                return items;
        }).catch((err) => {

            return Observable.of([]);

        });
```

Any idea why I am not able to get custom header info.

Comment: Helpful link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673089/why-is-access-control-expose-headers-needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since not all headers are allowed to be accessed from client side, You need to expose the "X-COUNT" header from the server side. "access-control-expose-headers" is used for that purpose.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A discussion on this topic: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5237.
`access-control-expose-headers`  description for more read: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers.