# Angular HttpClient unable to read response headers

Tags: angular, azure-functions, angular-httpclient

I am trying to get the location header in the response from an post like this:

```js
this.httpClient.post<Response>(url, data, { observe: 'response'}).subscribe(response => {
     const locationHeader = response.headers.get('Location');     
});
```

But no headers are available. Inspecting the traffic in fiddler verifies that the headers are there in the response... Why are the Location header not appearing in the headers property in the httpclient?

[image: options request]

### [image: post with location in response]

Edit 1: Using azure functions emulator locally for backend api. My understanding is that this by default is supposed to allow all headers based on this: [Configuring Access-Control-Allow-Headers in Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45864722/configuring-access-control-allow-headers-in-azure-functions)

Edit 2: Images from sample request with headers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading Custom HTTP response headers in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946396/reading-custom-http-response-headers-in-angular-2)

Comment: Using azure functions emulator locally for backend api. My understanding is that this by default is supposed to allow all headers...