# Receiving null Authorization header in Spring Boot from requests with Angular 7 but Postman works fine

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, cors, jwt

I am receiving a null Authorization header when I am sending a request to a back-end controller designed with Spring Boot. But when I am sending the same request with Postman, the correct API is hit and data is properly fetched from the back-end.

On the Spring Boot side, here's the code for `JwtSecurityConfiguration.java`:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "**/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.headers().cacheControl();
    }
```

I am receiving the `null` authorization header in `JwtAuthenticationToken.java`:

```
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (header == null || !header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            System.err.println("Header: " + header);
            LOGGER.error("JWT Token is either missing from HTTP header or has been provided in an incorrect format!");
            throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(
                    "JWT Token is either missing from HTTP header or has been provided in an incorrect format!");
        }
        String authenticationToken = header.substring(7);
        JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuthenticationToken = new JwtAuthenticationToken(authenticationToken);
        LOGGER.error("JWT Token has been received successfully. Authentication is in progress...");
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(jwtAuthenticationToken);
    }
```

On the Angular side of the equation, I am using HTTP interceptors to add the JWT token to every request sent. Here's how my `HttpInterceptorAuth.service.ts` looks:

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let jwtAuthHeader = this._authSvc.getAuthorizedToken();
    let jwtAuthUsername = this._authSvc.getLoggedInUsername();

    if (jwtAuthHeader && jwtAuthUsername) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: jwtAuthHeader
        }
      });
    }
    console.log(request);
    return next.handle(request);
  }
```

Since I'm logging the request sent by the HTTP interceptor, this is how it is in the Chrome console:

[image: Modified request after HTTP interceptor intercepts and adds JWT Auth Token]

On the Network tab in Chrome Dev Tools, this is the request that's sent by Chrome:
[image: Actual request sent by Chrome]

Notice that the `OPTIONS` request fails with `401 Unauthorized`.

This is probably because on the backend side, I am receiving an empty Authorization header when HTTP Interceptor has updated the request with the JWT Token in Authorization header.

I have no idea why the request that's actually sent is different from the one updated by HTTP interceptor. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: The browser won't add Authorization to a preflight OPTIONS request. Spring Security has CORS handling built in, you just need to enable it; see e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cors-preflight

Comment: Seems like a backend issue, your angular code looks fine.

Comment: Okay. This is the first time I'm working with JWT. The thing is I need to access a controller API in Spring boot from angular which requires a JWT token for hitting the Spring boot controller API. That JWT token is what I need to send in the Authorization header. Since Authorization header is present, the browser sends the preflight request check. So, how do I avoid the preflight request check then?

Comment: You don't avoid it, you handle it correctly. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS.

Comment: Do you have any pointers as to how to modify my backend code so that I can correctly handle the preflight requests? I am not aware if preflight requests even need to be handled explicitly from the backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I avoid the preflight request check then?

You can not disable or avoid the Preflight request mechanism for CORS origins.

> [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is a mechanism that uses
>   additional HTTP headers to tell browsers to give a web application
>   running at one origin, access to selected resources from a different
>   origin. A web application executes a cross-origin HTTP request when it
>   requests a resource that has a different origin (domain, protocol, or
>   port) from its own

To Resolve that you can use `CorsConfigurationSource` or `@CrossOrigin`

```
@Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "content-type", "x-auth-token"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

---

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*",allowCredentials = ,allowedHeaders = , exposedHeaders = , methods = , value = )
```

[Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52754448/10961238)

Answer (score 1):

To Resolve that you can use in your controller the annotation:

```
 @CrossOrigin (origins = "*" , exposedHeaders = "**")
```

Change * for your origin link, and ** for the specific token to expose.

Example:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", exposedHeaders = "token")
@RestController
public class AuthenticationController {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private TokenService tokenService;

    @PostMapping("/auth")
    public ResponseEntity<?> autenticar(@RequestBody @Valid UserDTO userDTO){
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken userData = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDTO.getUserName(), userDTO.getPassword());
        try {
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(userData);
            String token = tokenService.generateToken(authentication);
            HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            responseHeaders.set("token", token);

            return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(responseHeaders).build();
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explicitly excluded the preflight requests from authorization in your Spring Security configuration. Remember that Spring Security will secure all endpoints by default.

As a result, your API also expects an authorization token in the `OPTIONS` request.

Spring provides an out-of-the-box solution to exclude `OPTIONS` requests from authorization checks:

In your `JwtSecurityConfiguration.java`, include `http.cors();` at the end of the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method. This will add the Spring-provided CorsFilter to the application context, bypassing the authorization checks for OPTIONS requests